# How to add "OR" Condition in LinkedEntity QueryExpression Class in MS CRM

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework-4, dynamics-crm

I'm trying to retrieve data from both parent and child entity in MS CRM.

I wrote the code in QueryExpression Class

I want to know how to add "OR" condition in LinkedEntity Query in `QueryExpression` Class.

```
expOpp.LinkEntities[0].LinkCriteria.Conditions.Add(new ConditionExpression("statecode", ConditionOperator.Equal, 1));
```

In the above code i need to add "OR" condition.

Please help me how to make it.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Do you need to combine conditions for one (linked) entity with an Or-clause? Or do you need to retrieve parent and child entities, even when child entities do not exist? If the first is true you need an Or-operator on a `FilterExpression`, otherwise you need a left outer join.

Comment: Hello Henk, Im trying to achieve child record with "OR" condtion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add an "or" condition on a linked entity like this (thank you henk for updating my knowledge!):

```
var queryExpression = new QueryExpression("contact");
var linkToAccount = queryExpression.AddLink("account", "parentcustomerid", "accountid");
linkToAccount.LinkCriteria.FilterOperator = LogicalOperator.Or;
linkToAccount.LinkCriteria.Conditions.Add(new ConditionExpression("field1", ConditionOperator.Equal, true));
linkToAccount.LinkCriteria.Conditions.Add(new ConditionExpression("field2", ConditionOperator.Equal, 100000001));
queryExpression.LinkEntities.Add(linkToAccount);
```

Or what you can also do is create an "or" filter on the linked entity and add conditions to that:

```
var queryExpression = new QueryExpression("contact");
var linkToAccount = queryExpression.AddLink("account", "parentcustomerid", "accountid");
var filter = linkToAccount.LinkCriteria.AddFilter(LogicalOperator.Or);
filter.Conditions.Add(new ConditionExpression("field1", ConditionOperator.Equal, true));
filter.Conditions.Add(new ConditionExpression("field2", ConditionOperator.Equal, 100000001));
queryExpression.LinkEntities.Add(linkToAccount);
```

Comment: Yes, it *is* possible to set the Or-operator directly: `expOpp.LinkEntities[0].LinkCriteria.FilterOperator = LogicalOperator.Or`

Comment: Indeed you can. And it seems to work the same way. I always used filters! I shall update my answer to reflect this. Thank you

Comment: Well, the `LinkCriteria` property actually *is* a `FilterExpression`. In other words, when you add an extra filter you just add extra parenthesis around your conditions.